# fast hash bucket into 1 and n in python

Tags: python, hash

I have a list /array of 5000 integer values,
and integer are between 10000 and 20000.
There are  2060 different values of integer.

How to "re-hash" the initial values into [0-2059] ?
**without using assignement to a dict**

```
   13457 -->  0
   13260 -->  1
   14237 -->  2
```

initial order values of integer does not matter, it's just a rescaling.
Think one solution might to hash into [0-2599] bucket.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** My original answer (below) doesn't use a `dict`, but does use a `set`, so is not what the OP is asking for. [linpingta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549343/8951763) is correct, for example:

```
lst = [100 , 137 , 200 , 137]
new_lst = [lst.index(item) for item in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1]
```

This works because `lst.index(item)` returns the index of *the first* occurence of `item` in `lst`.

---

Original answer:

```
lst = [100 , 137 , 200 , 137]
new_lst = [list(set(lst)).index(item) for item in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: It looks fine, but is there a way to use hash ?

Comment: No, such a "hash" function which returns values in the range `[0, 2060)` would use a lookup table to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Using list.index(x) directly?

```
def f(l, x):
  return l.index(x) if x in l else -1
```

Comment: @Tensor this _does_ work, because `l.index(x)` returns the index of _the first_ occurence of `x` in `l`.